# Is it proper etiquette to keep religious content on official course page?

Tags: coursework, website, india, religious-issues

Is the course site property of the university or the person engaging it such as a teacher, teaching assistant etc.,?

Is it proper etiquette to add **religious contents such as quotes from religious texts, images of gods** into scientific course pages in a secular institute?

Comment: It strongly depends on the context. For example, it certainly is appropriate to do so in a religious studies course.

Comment: @xuq01 institute and course are science-based and secular....

Comment: I would not use the term "recommended" for sure. Moreover, I feel like that images of Gods are a bit inappropriate for such context.

Comment: Are you really asking if it is "recommended" (as in, you should do it most of the time) or if it is "ok" (as in, you can do it if you really want to)?

Comment: If you ask "Is it recommended", then you need to ask "from whom should that recommendation come"? I can give you my opinion, but there is no international body of universities that gives such recommendations.

Comment: @Shinary .... Yeah, the word recommendation or Okay is bad. I actually mean is whether proper etiquette or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, probably not, but there are cases where it might be reasonable. Religion is an immensely powerful force in human society, so inevitably it will impinge on science and sometimes it's appropriate to talk about that.

For example, the science of evolution has been under attack since its inception by those who believe in a literal reading of the Old Testament and other such texts. In a course on evolution it might be quite appropriate to present a quote from the Book of Genesis in order to discuss that opposition to evolution. What would *not* be appropriate there is to present it uncritically, casting young-earth creationism as some sort of equally-valid alternative to evolution.

Robert Oppenheimer apparently named the Trinity nuclear test after a [religious poem by John Donne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Sonnets#Sonnet_XIV_and_the_Trinity_site), and he famously quoted two passages from the Bhagavad Gita to express his reaction to the first nuclear explosion:

> If the radiance of a thousand suns were to burst at once into the sky,
>   that would be like the splendor of the mighty one.
>
> Now I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds.

Those passages are tremendously evocative and have been re-quoted many times. There's even a Linkin Park album named for the "thousand suns" line. I wouldn't consider it improper for a text on nuclear physics to include those quotes.

Answer (score 3):

> Is [a] course [web]site['s content] property of the university or the person [responsible for the course]?

The answer will depend on local law, but content on course websites will typically constitute work product of the person that produced the content, and work product is typically owned by the person's employer. Hence, content is probably owned by the university, rather than the content producer.

Ownership isn't particular relevant to the remainder of the question, which asks

> [Whether adding] religious content [to web]pages [of a science course] is appropriate?

A course website serves to educate the course's students in the terms intended by the course. I don't see how religious content helps serve that goal for a scientific course. So, I'd consider such content inappropriate.